# `Undefined control sequence` error when trying to write the value of a \csname...\endcsname control-sequence to the log file

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging, sourcecode, csname

In reading the source-code of pgf's object-oriented programming module in `<pgf/tikz install dir>/modules/pgfmoduleoo.code.tex`, I wrote the following plain TeX manuscript to experiment with the module.

```
\input pgf.tex\relax%
\usepgfmodule{oo}\relax%
\pgfooclass{A}{\attribute a=1;}%
\bye
```

The manuscript compiled successfully with `pdftex`.

I then wished to see what a certain pgf source-code macro, which is defined at the end of the `\pgfoo@inherit@attributes` macro, expanded to during run-time. So I added the following code as the very last line of `\pgfoo@inherit@attributes`:

```
\wlog{watch: \csname pgfooY\pgfoo@classname .@pgfoo@process@attributes\endcsname}%
```

where the control-sequence `\csname ... \endcsname` was copied directly from the preceding line (the original last line of `\pgfoo@inherit@attributes`):

```
\expandafter\let\csname pgfooY\pgfoo@classname .@pgfoo@process@attributes\endcsname%
    \pgfoo@process@attributes
```

But now compiling the manuscript with `pdftex` yielded the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfooYsignal.@pgfoo@process@attributes ...ute@op 
                                                  {emitter}\pgfooYsignal@emi...
<inserted text> 
                }\endwrite 
\pgfoo@inherit@attributes ...ttributes\endcsname }

\pgfooclass@ ...methods \pgfoo@inherit@attributes 
                                                  \expandafter \let \csname ...
l.837 }
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to see the meaning of that token, rather than do its full expansion:

```
\input pgf.tex
\usepgfmodule{oo}

\catcode`@=11
\expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfoo@inherit@attributes\expandafter{%
  \pgfoo@inherit@attributes
  \wlog{watch:
    \expandafter\meaning\csname pgfooY\pgfoo@classname .@pgfoo@process@attributes\endcsname
  }%
}
\catcode`@=12

\pgfooclass{A}{\attribute a=1;}

\bye
```

This writes in the log file

```
watch: macro:->\pgfoo@attribute@op {a}\pgfooYA@a
```